# Select Range of Datetime Records while Including Last Record Outside of Range

Tags: mysql

I have this table (and some records)

```
 ------------ --------------------- 
| id         | date_time           |
 ------------ --------------------- 
|    2489143 | 2013-05-31 00:00:00 | 
|    2489144 | 2013-05-31 00:30:00 | 
|    2489145 | 2013-05-31 01:00:00 | 
|    2489146 | 2013-05-31 01:30:00 | 
|    2489147 | 2013-05-31 02:00:00 | 
|    2489148 | 2013-05-31 02:30:00 | 
|    2489149 | 2013-05-31 03:00:00 | 
|    2489150 | 2013-05-31 03:30:00 | 
|    2489151 | 2013-05-31 04:00:00 | 
|    2489152 | 2013-05-31 05:00:00 | 
 ------------ --------------------- 
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to get records between a time range, but also, I want to get the last record just out of the time range, for example:

```
select id, date_time 
from t1 
where date_time >= '2013-05-31 01:15:00' 
    && date_time <= '2013-05-31 02:20:00';
```

I get:

```
 ------------ --------------------- 
| id         | date_time           |
 ------------ --------------------- 
|    2489146 | 2013-05-31 01:30:00 | 
|    2489147 | 2013-05-31 02:00:00 | 
 ------------ ---------------------
```

But I want this:

```
 ------------ --------------------- 
| id         | date_time           |
 ------------ --------------------- 
|    2489145 | 2013-05-31 01:00:00 | 
|    2489146 | 2013-05-31 01:30:00 | 
|    2489147 | 2013-05-31 02:00:00 | 
 ------------ ---------------------
```

How can I query MySQL to get that result?

Comment: Why not just include the nearby record that is outside of the current range with a slightly larger range?

Comment: Why not the `'2013-05-31 02:30:00'` as well?

Comment: @ypercube Last record "just out" of time. `02:30` would be latest record.

Comment: @hjpotter92 No idea what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION` clause for the desired result:

```
(
    SELECT id, date_time
    FROM t1
    WHERE date_time < '2013-05-31 01:15:00'
    ORDER BY date_time DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT id, date_time 
    FROM t1 
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2013-05-31 01:15:00'
        AND '2013-05-31 02:20:00'
);
```

Comment: Ah, you got me for 40 seconds. Add parenthesis around the 2 Selects.

Comment: @ypercube hmm, /* googles about parenthesis in `UNION`s */ :) Thanks.

Comment: They are only needed because of the ORDER BY and the LIMIT.